# Get object in JavaScript array where appointments.id = calEvent.id

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-week-calendar

How can I get the object in the `appointments` array, where `appointments.id = calEvent.id`?

```
appointments.push({
  id: id,
  start: startFormatted,
  end: endFormatted, 
  title: '<b>' + title + '</b><br><div id="event_body">' + body + '</div>', 
  userId: userid,
  categoryId: categoryId,
  counterId: counter
});

eventRender : function(calEvent, $event) {
  var id = calEvent.id;

  // get the object in the appointments-array where appointments.id = calEvent.id
}
```

Comment: What is the object passed as `calEvent`?

Comment: It is a calendar event in the jQuery weekcalendar plugin. The calEvent.id is equal to one of appointments.id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through your `appointments` array an find the matching `id`. Try this:

```
eventRender : function(calEvent, $event) {
    var id = calEvent.id;        
    for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
        if (appointments[i].id == id) {
            // do something with the appointment...
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to loop through the array looking for the desired id:

```
for (var i = 0; i < appointments.length; i++) {
    if (appointments[i].id == calEvent.id) {
        // appointments[i] contains the desired id
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
appointments[id]={

    start: startFormatted,
    end: endFormatted, 
    title: '<b>' + title + '</b><br><div id="event_body">' + body + '</div>', 
    userId: userid,
    categoryId: categoryId,
    counterId: counter
};
```

then

```
eventRender : function(calEvent, $event) {
  var id = calEvent.id;
  // get the object in the appointments-array where appointments.id = calEvent.id
  var obj=appointments[id]
 }
```

poor index are always faster than fastidious looping & push is also slow
edit to add that if you can not change the way you build your appointments you can still loop through it one time to create an indexed array to be use by your eventrender function which will be more efficient than looping every single time eventrender is called. The biggest your appointments, the most the necessity to index obviously

Comment: it is if you set it as such - useless comment @doonot ; indexing once is way faster than looping every time

Comment: @doonot also see edit to my answer; to formulate differently, instead of pushing an object with id property set to id, you add an element to your array with the index set to id (& that then don't even need an id property); anyway if you prefer to loop forever that's your call i guess